# Cannot deserialize XML string to object containing List

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

Here is my serialization methods:

```
public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
{
    try
    {
         var root = new XmlRootAttribute()
         {
             ElementName = "PatientDS",
             Namespace = ""
         };

         T result;
         var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), root);
         using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
         {
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
         }
         return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    try
    {
       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
       using (var writer = new StringWriter())
       {
           serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
           return writer.ToString();
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here is the object I am trying to deserialize to:

```
public class PatientDS
{
    [XmlElement("Patient")]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

    [Serializable]
    public class Patient
    {
        [XmlElement("PatientID")]
        public Guid PatientID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PatientCategory")]
        public string PatientCategory { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SiteOfDisease")]
        public string SiteOfDisease { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Outcome")]
        public string Outcome { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RegistrationYear")]
        public int RegistrationYear { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RegistrationNo")]
        public int RegistrationNo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RegistrationDate")]
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("IDNumber")]
        public string IDNumber { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("BirthDate")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TypeOfResistantTB")]
        public string TypeOfResistantTB { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TreatmentStartDate")]
        public DateTime TreatmentStartDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OutcomeDate")]
        public DateTime OutcomeDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("IsActive")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("IsTreatmentStarted")]
        public bool IsTreatmentStarted { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TypeOfResistantTBConfirmation")]
        public string TypeOfResistantTBConfirmation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("HIVStatus")]
        public string HIVStatus { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("PatientDSTDS")]
        [XmlArrayItem("PatientDST")]
        public List<PatientDST> PatientDSTDS { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PatientHIVTestDS")]
        public List<PatientHIVTest> PatientHIVTestDS { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PatientDSTAdvancedDS")]
        public List<PatientDSTAdvanced> PatientDSTAdvancedDS { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PatientSecondLineDrugDS")]
        public List<PatientSecondLineDrug> PatientSecondLineDrugDS { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PatientSputumDS")]
        public List<PatientSputum> PatientSputumDS { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PatientDS>
  <Patient>
    <PatientID>ED526A85-26E3-424A-B15C-AB32FD114F5E</PatientID>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <PatientCategory>N</PatientCategory>
    <SiteOfDisease>PTB</SiteOfDisease>
    <Outcome></Outcome>
    <RegistrationYear>2010</RegistrationYear>
    <RegistrationNo>100</RegistrationNo>
    <RegistrationDate>2010-06-21</RegistrationDate>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
    <Surname>Doe</Surname>
    <IDNumber>7001010099080</IDNumber>
    <BirthDate>1970-01-01</BirthDate>
    <TypeOfResistantTB>MDR</TypeOfResistantTB>
    <TreatmentStartDate>2010-06-21</TreatmentStartDate>
    <OutcomeDate>2010-11-30</OutcomeDate>
    <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    <IsTreatmentStarted>1</IsTreatmentStarted>
    <TypeOfResistantTBConfirmation>LABCONFIRMED</TypeOfResistantTBConfirmation>
    <HIVStatus>P</HIVStatus>
    <PatientDSTDS>
     <PatientDST>
      <TestDate>2010-06-22 08:23:00.000</TestDate>
      <ReferenceNo>NNY0288029</ReferenceNo>
      <PatientDSTDrugDS>
        <PatientDSTDrug>
          <DSTDrug>R</DSTDrug>
          <DSTResult>R</DSTResult>
        </PatientDSTDrug>
        <PatientDSTDrug>
          <DSTDrug>Eto</DSTDrug>
          <DSTResult>S</DSTResult>
        </PatientDSTDrug>
     </PatientDSTDrugDS>
  </PatientDST>
  <PatientDST>
    <PatientDSTID>FBFA09A9-452B-4BA2-BC01-81297EFCC8FD</PatientDSTID>
    <TestDate>2011-07-11 15:50:49.000</TestDate>
    <ReferenceNo>NTH0168507</ReferenceNo>
    <PatientDSTDrugDS>
      <PatientDSTDrug>
        <DSTDrug>R</DSTDrug>
        <DSTResult>R</DSTResult>
      </PatientDSTDrug>
      <PatientDSTDrug>
        <DSTDrug>Eto</DSTDrug>
        <DSTResult>S</DSTResult>
      </PatientDSTDrug>
   </PatientDSTDrugDS>
</PatientDST>
</PatientDSTDS>
<PatientHIVTestDS>
  <PatientHIVTest>
    <HIVTestResult>N</HIVTestResult>
    <TestDate>2010-02-01 00:00:00.000</TestDate>
    <CD4Count>350</CD4Count>
  </PatientHIVTest>
  <PatientHIVTest>
    <HIVTestResult>P</HIVTestResult>
    <TestDate>2010-09-25 00:00:00.000</TestDate>
    <CD4Count>280</CD4Count>
  </PatientHIVTest>
</PatientHIVTestDS>
<PatientDSTAdvancedDS>
  <PatientDSTAdvanced>
    <DSTDrugResult>R</DSTDrugResult>
    <DSTGeneXpertResult>Positive</DSTGeneXpertResult>
    <TestDate>2010-07-11 16:30:00.000</TestDate>
    <ReferenceNo>ABCD9928</ReferenceNo>
  </PatientDSTAdvanced>
  <PatientDSTAdvanced>
    <DSTDrugResult>N</DSTDrugResult>
    <DSTGeneXpertResult>Negative</DSTGeneXpertResult>
    <TestDate>2011-01-18 16:30:00.000</TestDate>
    <ReferenceNo>WXYZ9876</ReferenceNo>
  </PatientDSTAdvanced>
</PatientDSTAdvancedDS>
<PatientSecondLineDrugDS>
  <PatientSecondLineDrug>
    <SecondLineDrug>Ofx</SecondLineDrug>
    <StartDate>2010-09-25 00:00:00.000</StartDate>
  </PatientSecondLineDrug>
  <PatientSecondLineDrug>
    <SecondLineDrug>Bdq</SecondLineDrug>
    <StartDate>2010-10-13 00:00:00.000</StartDate>
  </PatientSecondLineDrug>
</PatientSecondLineDrugDS>
<PatientSputumDS>
  <PatientSputum>
    <SputumResult>R</SputumResult>
    <CultureResult>N</CultureResult>
    <TestDate>2010-06-22 00:00:00.000</TestDate>
    <ReferenceNo>ABC0168503</ReferenceNo>
    <TreatmentMonth>1</TreatmentMonth>
  </PatientSputum>
  <PatientSputum>
    <SputumResult>N</SputumResult>
    <CultureResult>P</CultureResult>
    <TestDate>2010-08-17 00:00:00.000</TestDate>
    <ReferenceNo>XYZ0358503</ReferenceNo>
    <TreatmentMonth>2</TreatmentMonth>
  </PatientSputum>
</PatientSputumDS>
```

The problem is that I am able to deserialize this object, and all the normal elements are populated with the correct values, but I cannot get the List<> properties to populate.

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: How does your XML look?

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy I have added the XML

Comment: I deleted my answer as it's the same as your code. Works on my machine as shown in the screenshot though. There must be some subtle difference we are overlooking

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy Do you maybe want to undelete your answer, so that I can compare a few things quick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

After reading more about reading dates from an XML, I figured the dates provided in the sub items of this XML is not valid (ISO 8601) standard, and therefore my application was struggling to read it, and failed.

As this was a dummy XML, I instantiated a new PersonDS object, deserialized it to an XML, and then serialized back to check if the application was working, and it serialized with no problem.

Thanks all for their help.

Comment: Ah good catch. Since I didn't have the subclasses I let the VS auto-generate them and added TestDate as string just to see the deserialization. That was the difference between our codes then. Thanks for posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I used the XML and the sample code above it didn't populate any of the fields for me. I'm not entirely clear that you're desalinizing into Patient directly but when I added a PatientDS class which is the root in XML it populated all fields including all the lists. I just added this bit:

```
public class PatientDS
{
    [XmlElement("Patient")]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

and I deserialized like this:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
var patient = DeserializeFromXml<PatientDS>(xml);
```

and the output seems fine:

[image]

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I was using a PatientDS class as follow: public class PatientDS
    {
        [XmlElement("Patient")]
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
Why are you declaring the the Patient Property as a list?

Comment: No reason, I didn't know the structure of PatientDS so I just assumed there may be multiple Patient objects. I replaced it with the single Patient and it still works. So that means I didn't do anything you haven't done but works on my machine. Weird.

Comment: I updated my Original Post. Our code seems to be the same, but I cannot get the same results on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PatientDS")]
public class PatientDS
{
   public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Patient")]
public class Patient
{
   //stuff
}
```

And deserialize it.